# Android ViewPager with fragments wont launch

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I've been trying to get this working for sometime now and everything I've tried has failed so this is my last resort..

So basically I'm developing an App that allows you to swipe between the screens
There will only be two screens that i will be swiping between. When the App launches a res/splash_layout.xml screen will appear(either ill click a button to start the rest or automatically switch). Then you should be able to swipe between res/maps_layout.xml and res/markers_layout.xml. But for some weird reason the app wont launch

Any Ideas or solutions would be much appreciated 
Regards
Joe

**Source Code Below:**

res/splash_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

res/maps_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#00FF00"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

</RelativeLayout>
```

res/markers_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#0000FF"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then we have the **SRC** code

src/PagerAdapter.java

```
package joe.wit.app.locophoto;

import java.util.List;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {



    private List<Fragment> fragments;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
        super(fm);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.fragments = fragments;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.fragments.get(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.fragments.size();
    }

}
```

src/Splash.java

```
package joe.wit.app.locophoto;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class Splash extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if(container == null){
            return null;
        }

        return (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.splash_layout, container);
    }



}
```

src/Markers.java

```
package joe.wit.app.locophoto;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class Markers extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if(container == null){
            return null;
        }

        return (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.markers_layout, container);
    }



}
```

src/Map.java

```
package joe.wit.app.locophoto;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class Map extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if(container == null){
            return null;
        }

        return (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_layout, 
                container, false);
    }



}
```

src/MainActivity.java

```
package joe.wit.app.locophoto;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;




public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_layout);
        inistialisePaging();
    }

    private void inistialisePaging() {
        List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Map.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Markers.class.getName()));

        mPagerAdapter =new PagerAdapter(this.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);

        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);        
    }

}
```

Latest Logcat Error

```
 02-10 10:42:44.045: E/AndroidRuntime(21334): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-10 10:42:44.045: E/AndroidRuntime(21334): Process: joe.wit.app.locophoto, PID: 21334
02-10 10:42:44.045: E/AndroidRuntime(21334): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v4.view.ViewPager cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout
02-10 10:42:44.045: E/AndroidRuntime(21334):    at joe.wit.app.locophoto.Markers.onCreateView(Markers.java:19)
02-10 10:42:44.045: E/AndroidRuntime(21334):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786)
02-10 10:42:44.045: E/AndroidRuntime(21334):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
02-10 10:42:44.045: E/AndroidRuntime(21334):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
02-10 10:42:44.045: E/AndroidRuntime(21334):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
02-10 10:42:44.045: E/AndroidRuntime(21334):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1489)
02-10 10:42:44.045: E/AndroidRuntime(21334):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:486)
02-10 10:42:44.045: E/AndroidRuntime(21334):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
02-10 10:42:44.045: E/AndroidRuntime(21334):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1073)
02-10 10:42:44.045: E/AndroidRuntime(21334):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919)
02-10 10:42:44.045: E/AndroidRuntime(21334):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1441)
02-10 10:42:44.045: E/AndroidRuntime(21334):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16660)
02-10 10:42:44.045: E/AndroidRuntime(21334):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
02-10 10:42:44.045: E/AndroidRuntime(21334):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
02-10 10:42:44.045: E/AndroidRuntime(21334):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16660)
02-10 10:42:44.045: E/AndroidRuntime(21334):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5150)
02-10 10:42:44.045: E/AndroidRuntime(21334):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
02-10 10:42:44.045: E/AndroidRuntime(21334):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16660)
02-10 10:42:44.045: E/AndroidRuntime(21334):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5150)
02-10 10:42:44.045: E/AndroidRuntime(21334):    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:327)
02-10 10:42:44.045: E/AndroidRuntime(21334):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16660)
02-10 10:42:44.045: E/AndroidRuntime(21334):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5150)
02-10 10:42:44.045: E/AndroidRuntime(21334):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
02-10 10:42:44.045: E/AndroidRuntime(21334):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2421)
02-10 10:42:44.045: E/AndroidRuntime(21334):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16660)
02-10 10:42:44.045: E/AndroidRuntime(21334):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2058)
02-10 10:42:44.045: E/AndroidRuntime(21334):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1189)
02-10 10:42:44.045: E/AndroidRuntime(21334):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1374)
02-10 10:42:44.045: E/AndroidRuntime(21334):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1076)
02-10 10:42:44.045: E/AndroidRuntime(21334):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5905)
02-10 10:42:44.045: E/AndroidRuntime(21334):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:807)
02-10 10:42:44.045: E/AndroidRuntime(21334):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:601)
02-10 10:42:44.045: E/AndroidRuntime(21334):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:562)
02-10 10:42:44.045: E/AndroidRuntime(21334):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:791)
02-10 10:42:44.045: E/AndroidRuntime(21334):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
02-10 10:42:44.045: E/AndroidRuntime(21334):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-10 10:42:44.045: E/AndroidRuntime(21334):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
02-10 10:42:44.045: E/AndroidRuntime(21334):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5633)
02-10 10:42:44.045: E/AndroidRuntime(21334):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-10 10:42:44.045: E/AndroidRuntime(21334):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-10 10:42:44.045: E/AndroidRuntime(21334):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:896)
02-10 10:42:44.045: E/AndroidRuntime(21334):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:712)
02-10 10:42:44.045: E/AndroidRuntime(21334):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please explain, completely and precisely, what "the app wont launch" means. Are you crashing? If so, when you examined LogCat and looked at the Java stack trace, what did you see?

Comment: https://beingsouthafricando.files.wordpress.com/2010/12/image001.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Map` and `Markers` classes, replace

```
return (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_layout, 
            container, false);
```

with

```
return (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_layout, 
            container, false);
```

Also, in your `Markers` class, it is important that you use

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.markers_layout, container, false);
```

and not

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.markers_layout, container);
```

Basically, the `ViewGroup` root must **NOT** act as the parent of the `RelativeLayout`, hence the `false` parameter must be passed.

Try this. This should work.

Comment: @Irishdiablo: Have you tried this ? are you still facing a problem ??

Comment: Yes I've added this fix but unforunately im still getting a fata exception

Comment: I have seen the latest error log ... Please update all XML and JAVA files in your question ... I think you have made some changes in your code which are not reflected in your question.

Comment: Please see the edited answer and try it out. Let me know whether it works or not.

Comment: Thanks you very much for your time...This has been bothering me for a few days now...Finally i can move on with this project Regards Irishdiablo

Answer (score 0):

Markers.java and Map.java you're casting the wrong class to the layout.

change this:

```
return (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.markers_layout, container);
```

to:

```
return (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.markers_layout, container);
```

Comment: It should be slightly different now, please recheck.

Comment: Currently walking to my car will check when I get home.. Cheers for this help